# Storing received XMPP message in a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am designing a chat application for iOS using Robbie Hanson's XMPP framework: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

I am able to store the messages which I am sending into a dictionary which is the datasource for my tableview using the following code:

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage {

    NSString *messageStr = messageField.text;
    if([messageStr length] > 0) {
        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
        [body setStringValue:messageStr];
        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:chatWithUser];
        [message addChild:body];
        [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:message];

        NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [m setObject:messageStr forKey:@"msg"];
        [m setObject:@"you" forKey:@"sender"];
        [messages addObject:m];
        [self.tView reloadData];
    }
}
```

But the didReceiveMessage is defined inside the AppDelegate and I am not able to store the received messages inside the local dictionary, hence not able to display in the TableView. My didReceiveMessage function looks like this:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    // A simple example of inbound message handling.

    if ([message isChatMessageWithBody])
    {
        XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from]
                                                                 xmppStream:xmppStream
                                                       managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

        NSString *messageBody = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
        NSString *displayName = [user jidStr];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
        {

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayName
                                                              message:messageBody
                                                             delegate:nil 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];

        }
        else
        {
            // We are not active, so use a local notification instead
            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
            localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\n\n%@",displayName,messageBody];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
        }
    }
}
```

How can I store the messages into my dictionary of messages inside ChatViewController.m where sendMessage is defined?

Comment: Keep a reference to the object the dictionary is in, expose the dictionary through a property, use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate a module called `XMPPMessageArchiving`. With this module you can save all the outgoing and incoming messages (Sent/Received messages).

```
XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage *xmppMessageStorage = [XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
XMPPMessageArchiving *xmppMessageArchiving = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:xmppMessageStorage];

[xmppMessageArchiving activate:xmppStream];
[xmppMessageArchiving addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

This extension is XEP 136 (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) and you can use all the classes included in `XMPPFramework`. By the way, if you show all the messages in a Table View Controller you can use NSFetchedResultController to refresh that Table View every time that a new object has been inserted (i.e a new message has been sent or received).

Comment: Hello @moral , What to do in case of MUC ? How to activate XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create method for your ViewController such as `- (void)addMessage:(NSDictionary *)messageProperties` in which you add that message to your array and reload the tableView. If you have a reference of that ViewController in your AppDelegate you can just call it from there.

The call in your AppDelegates method would like this:

```
[self.chatViewController addMessage:messageDictionary];
```

Comment: I am new in this, can I see some code to understand it better? Specially, how to call the dictionary from the AppDelegate? My message is getting received at AppDelegate and I am trying to display from ChatViewController.

Comment: I cannot say how to exactly do it in your case because I have no information on the layout of your app. If ChatViewController happens to be your windows rootViewController you can simply cast that rootViewController and use the method.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to store them in local sqlite so that you can later retrieve old messages easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the information with the protocols in this way

in the **AppDelegate**:

```
    protocol ChatDelegate {
    func MassageRecibed(name: String)
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, XMPPStreamDelegate, XMPPRosterDelegate {


    var delegate:ChatDelegate! = nil
    func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) {
          delegate?.MassageRecibed(name: body)
       }

}
```

and to get the information in the view you want, you just have to implement this protocol, Implement the delegate to the Appdelegate.

in the **ChatViewController**

```
    class ChatViewController: UIViewController, ChatDelegate {

     let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            appDelegate.delegate = self

        }

        func MassageRecibed(name: String) {
            print("mensaje recibido", name)

        }
}
```